# placing bets to maximize the difference between two random numbers

Tags: uniform-distribution

Suppose you are asked to bet on the difference between two independent randomly numbers $r_1$ and $r_2$, both uniformly distributed between 0 and 1. Your bet size is $w$ is between -1 and 1. Your winning each time will be $w_i \cdot (r_1 - r_2)$.

Of course the expectation of this bet is zero. But suppose now you know the value of $r_1$ before placing your bet, what is the optimal bet size that will maximize your sharp ratio: $\frac{E[w_(r_{1}-r_{2})]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[w\cdot(r_1-r_2)]}}$ , assuming that you can change your bet size each time, and you repeat this process many times?

Comment: do you know all $r_1$s before any bet or know $r_1$ right before your each bet and after your previous bets?

Comment: You know one $r_1$ right before you place each bet.

Comment: This question is singularly uninteresting: since all positive bets give identical values of that ratio and all negative bets give the negatives of those values, you are asking your readers merely to choose the larger of a number and its negative.

Comment: @whuber, I think that will maximize the expectation, but not necessarily sharpe ratio

Comment: Ah, I guess OP didn't make it clear. My understanding is that the sharpe ratio isn't taken on each bet. There is (infinitely) many rounds of betting, each earns you $x_i = w_i(r_{1i}-r_{2i})$, and you wish to maximize avg($x_i$) / std($x_i$)

Comment: The "sharp ratio" simplifies because $w$ factors out of the expectation and $|w|$ factors out of the square root of the variance.  Therefore only the *sign* of the bet, not the amount, has any effect on that ratio.

Comment: I guess I didn't clarify this, but the bet size is different each time depending on your knowledge of $r_1$, so I don't think it can be factored.

Comment: The question states that you know $r_1$. Therefore the bet is chosen based on an expectation of $r_2$ given that $r_1$ is known. Averaging over $r_1$ is not relevant to this optimization.

Comment: your bet size should be dependent on r1, and that's the whole idea behind this. So I am not sure what you meant by "averaging over r1 is not relevant", or "only the sign matter"

Comment: If the goal is to only maximize the expectation, then this becomes too easy, just bet 1 when r>0.5 and vice versa. The standard deviation is suppose to encourage betting small when the chance of winning is small.

Answer (score 0):

Sharp ratio simplifies to

$\text{sign}(w) \sqrt{12} (r_1 - E(r_2))$

So, by way of "thinkin' about it", you just choose $w > 0$ if $r_1 > 0$ or $w < 0$ if $r_1 < 0$.

Comment: I believe you meant to use $1/2$ (which is $E(r_2)$) rather than $0$ in your criterion.